# Ubuntu 20 python: "OverflowError: mktime argument out of range"

Tags: python, time

**Enviroment**

OS version: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

python version: python3.8.5/python3.7.1

pendulum: 1.4.4

**Details**

I am using airlfow1.10.12. And I find the boom like this `OverflowError: mktime argument out of range` when I explore the landing times.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSdRZ.png)

I look into it and find that it may be an OS issue. I test python3.8.5 and python3.7.1 in Ubuntu16.04, and it is all right. But in Ubuntu20.04.2, both python3.8.5 and python3.7.1 get the error.

In Ubuntu20.04.2, When I upgrade pendulum to 2.0.0 or greater, I will work. But airflow1.10.12 requires pendulum==1.4.4 and it can not start with pendlum==2.0.

**How to reproduce it:**

```
pip install pendulum==1.4.4
```

```
import pendulum
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import time

dt = datetime(2022, 1, 24, 0, 10)
a=pendulum.tz.timezone('Asia/Singapore')
time2 = dt.replace(tzinfo=a)
time2.timetuple()
time.mktime(time2.timetuple())
```

Comment: When I upgrade pendulum to 2.0.0 or greater, I will work.  But airflow1.10.12 requires pendulum==1.4.4 and it can not start with pendlum==2.0.0

Comment: Best to add that info to the question via edit rather then as a comment.